# How do I add File to SVN without Checking out

Tags: svn

I would like to add a file to a remote svn repository without checking out the project.

`svn add` requires the project to be checked out

`svn import` seems to only import directories

Any ideas?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be able to use `svn import`:

```
$ svn help import
import: Commit an unversioned file or tree into the repository.
```

Import is able to add individual files and trees to a repository.

Comment: +1 `svn import` works with a single file. `svn import file.txt http://svn.example.com/repo/trunk/file.txt`

Comment: If you need to specify user and password from shell, might help you:    svn import --non-interactive --username theusername --password the password -m "Comment" /path/to/file http://path/to/svn/repo/filename

Comment: To add multiple files, you need to put them in a  separate folder, chdir to that folder and add the current durectlory, too bad it does not work like `cp`.

Answer (score 34):

I think it got it. The secret is to include the file name on the url

```
svn import -m "Adding just a file" file_name http://path/to/svn/repo/file_name
```

Comment: Spot on, only thing I would add is, you could use a different file_name at the repository side, for example svn import -m "Adding just a file" file_name http://path/to/svn/repo/other_file_name

Answer (score 4):

This might not be what you are looking for but you can use -N flag to checkout a code non-recursively.

Example:

```
svn co -N http://svn.example.com/repo/trunk
```

This will not checkout all the sub-directories. Which is much faster if you are just trying to add a file.

Comment: With a more recent SVN you can use `--depth=empty` which won't check out any files at all.

Answer (score -7):

SCMs are meant to version your code. Perhaps you want to use an FTP server.

Comment: I can't see how this answers any bit of the question?