# Add new files to existing repo without cloning

Tags: git, github

I'm looking for a way in Git to add new files to an existing remote repo without having to clone all of it.
I have a large repo on Github and I want to add a new folder at its root, but I don't want to clone the remote repo. Is there a way to do that?

Or maybe just clone the structure of the repo to be able to add it to the new folder and then push it?

Hope it's clear enough. I found some similar questions but no satisfying answer. Some directed to submodules, but not sure that's appropriate for me.
And even though it says here [How do I add file to remote Git repo (Github) without cloning the whole repo first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619450/how-do-i-add-file-to-remote-git-repo-github-without-cloning-the-whole-repo-fir) that it can't be done, Im sure there must be a way :)

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add file to remote Git repo (Github) without cloning the whole repo first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619450/how-do-i-add-file-to-remote-git-repo-github-without-cloning-the-whole-repo-fir)

Comment: `Or maybe just clone the structure of the repo` - that's a [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

Answer (score 4):

Use web GUI, press button. Or drag and drop to webpage.

[image]

Or create a new empty file put inside a folder:

[image]

Reference:

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-file-to-a-repository/

https://github.com/blog/2105-upload-files-to-your-repositories

Comment: Thanks, but it's not just about adding an empty folder, but a folder with multiple files in it

Comment: Drag and drop your folder (with many files inside) into Github webpage

Comment: Ok. Thanks, didn't know you could do that. that could work for me.

Comment: But if there is a way to do it in a clean way with Git that would probably be better