# how to merge new contents to remote git repo without cloning locally first?

Tags: git

I have a repo on github and I want to add some new files to it, but I don't want to clone the remote repo on my local system.  How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add file to remote Git repo (Github) without cloning the whole repo first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19619450/how-do-i-add-file-to-remote-git-repo-github-without-cloning-the-whole-repo-fir)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check that one, if it works I'll delete this post.