# How to add a file to a Git repository using GitHub API?

Tags: git, github, github-api

It is possible to add (commit) a new file to a Git repository in a browser according to [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/creating-new-files).

I want to do the same in my Java application.

Where can I find GitHub API documentation for the API call that is being used here?

Here are the request data I found using Firefox:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The GitHub v3 API doc for creating or updating a file in a repo is [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents)

Comment: @MadhuBhat Thanks. If you submit the comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/42571004/441757

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **creating or updating file contents** in a GitHub repo, you can use the below GitHub v3 API

```
PUT /repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}
```

The documentation of the above API can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/rest/reference/repos#create-or-update-file-contents).

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X PUT -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"message":"Commit message","content":"<file_content>","branch":"<branch_name>"}' https://api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contents/{path}
```