# E145000: New entry name required when importing a file

Tags: svn

I try to do upload a release note from my Ubuntu to a SVN repository:

```
svn import -m "Release Notes" Release_Notes_2.2.0.pdf https://myrepo.com/svn/docs/ReleaseNotes/
```

This gives me the following error:

```
svn: E145000: New entry name required when importing a file
```

Anyone know the issue?

Answer (score 3):

Your answer can find here [How do I add File to SVN without Checking out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000587/how-do-i-add-file-to-svn-without-checking-out) .

```
svn import -m "Adding just a file" file_name http://path/to/svn/repo/file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

File name should be given in SVN URL. So, the command should be as follows.

```
svn import -m "Release Notes" Release_Notes_2.2.0.pdf https://myrepo.com/svn/docs/ReleaseNotes/Release_Notes_2.2.0.pdf
```

Thank you.